# Print pattern of asterisks with n per line, decrementing to 1, then back to n

Tags: php, loops, ascii-art

If the input is 3 then the output should be

```
***
**
*
**
***
```

In the same way, if the accepted values is 5 then the output should be

```
*****
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
*****
```

This is what I've done but its not correct

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
for ($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++)
{
    for ($col = 1; $col <= 6 - $row; $col++)
    {
        echo '*';
    }

    echo "\n";
}
for ($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++)
{
    for ($col = 1; $col <= $row; $col++)
    {
        echo '*';
    }

    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's with the nested `for` loops?

```
$lineBreak = "\r\n"; // This may need to be <br /> if carriage returns don't show in <pre>
$maxNum = 5;
echo '<pre>';
for ($i = $maxNum; $i > 0; $i--) {
    echo str_repeat('*', $i) . $lineBreak;
}
for ($i = 2; $i <= $maxNum; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat('*', $i) . $lineBreak;
}
echo '</pre>';
```

For fun, to eliminate one more `for` loop:

```
$lineBreak = "\r\n";
$maxNum = 5;
$out = '*';
for ($i = 2; $i <= $maxNum; $i++) {
    $out = str_repeat('*', $i) . $lineBreak . $out . $lineBreak . str_repeat('*', $i);
}
echo '<pre>' . $out . '</pre>';
```

Note that this code wouldn't be valid with `$maxNum < 1`.

To fetch a value from the user replace the `$maxNum` line with...

```
$maxNum = $_GET['maxNum'];
```

and load the page using `scriptname.php?maxNum=5`

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner for you :p

```
echo implode("\n",array_map(function($n) {return str_repeat("*",$n);},array_merge(range($input,1),range(2,$input))));
```

Broken down:

- Create a range of numbers from "input" down to 1
- Create a range of numbers from 2 up to "input" (prevents duplicate "1")
- Merge the two ranges, resulting in the "down-then-up" list
- Replace each item in the array with the appropriate number of stars
- Glue them together on new lines.

Note that you may need `<br />` instead of `\n` to output in a browser.

Comment: +1 Awesome, but I wouldn't really consider this a "one-liner" as it does so much and you could easily break the function down into multiple lines for readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think your professor is looking for recursion here..

Something like this should work -

```
function stars($num) {
  echo str_repeat('*', $num)."\n";

  if ($num > 1) {
    stars($num - 1);
    echo str_repeat('*', $num)."\n";
  }
}
```