# Line break for every addition

Tags: php, loops

I made a loop where it shows a number of asterisks based on what is placed on the input field:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $num1 = $_POST["num1"];
}

for($b=1; $b<=$num1; $b++){
            echo "*";
}
```

so if $num1 is 7 the output of the loop will be:

```
*******
```

I would like to turn them into a pyramid, my intention is to do something like this:

```
loop: 1 <br>
      2 <br>
      3 <br>
      2 (ran out of asterisks) <br>
```

so the output will be:

```
*
**
***
**
```

total is still what $num1 is

what loop can I use to get this?

Comment: https://www.phptpoint.com/print-star-pattern-php/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print star in PHP which takes one value and print something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366893/print-star-in-php-which-takes-one-value-and-print-something-like-this)

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799918/how-can-i-create-a-pyramid-from-using-php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12799918/2943403) and [Pyramid asterisk in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36731505/2943403) and [Asterisk pyramid using php while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40195579/2943403)

Comment: Your requirements are not clear.   You say that you want to print 7 asterisks, but your desired output displays 8 asterisks.  Please [edit].

Answer (score 0):

```
if you just want half pyramid: like this
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
    for($b=1; $b<=$num1; $b++){
            for($c=1; $c<=$b; $c++){
                echo '*';
            }
            echo "<br>";
          }

if you need pattern like this:
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*


for($b=1; $b<=$num1; $b++){
 for($c=1; $c<=$b; $c++){
        echo '*';
    }
    echo "<br>";
    
  }
  for($b=$num1; $b>=1; $b--){
    for($c=1; $c<=$b; $c++){
        echo '*';
    }
    echo "<br>";        
  }
```

Comment: you can add a space after * , for example '* ' like this, so it will look more prettier.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it